# space in app name - iOS

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

How do get a space in an app name for iOS (appc SDK 6.2.0).  In tiapp.xml I have the space in the name "My Appname" and when I publish to iTuneConnect it shows up as "MyAppname".

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: iTunesConnect does not takes the app name from your build or .ipa until the app is published. It is setup manually when you create a new app.

Comment: Thanks...and that's what I thought as well.  In iTunesConnect it set as "My Appname" (with the space) but on my TestFlight builds on the device it shows as "MyAppName".  Could TestFlights build with the dot next to them be forcing the removal of the space or is it something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a file i18n/en/app.xml with the following content:

```
<resources>
    <string name="appname">My App Name</string>
</resources>
```

Then it is localised by Titanium and shows up correctly on the device dashboard

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is where you put your app name which shows up on iTunesConnect. The app name which shows up with icon on iOS device springboard is the one you specify in tiapp.xml file.

Comment: Thank again for your help.  I think my initial description was a little ambiguous.  In trap.xml my app name has a space, in iTuneConnect my app name has a space, when I publish to my devices via TestFlight the app name on the device does not have the space (iOS11 GM).  Maybe it's a TestFlight or iOS11 bug, but I do have the space in the app name set in both places (tiapp.xml and iTunesConnect).

Comment: I am not sure about TestFlight as I always use Diawi.com.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known iOS 11 bug and as mentioned Sebastian, you should use file "app/i18n/en/app.xml" for localizing application name, but instead space, use `&#x2007;` code. Example for your app name (`My Appname` must be `My&#x2007;Appname`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="appname">My&#x2007;Appname</string>
</resources>
```